# How indexOn works in firebase-database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My database looks like the following:

```
"users": {
    "2387653478": {
        "score": 1000,
        ...
    },
    "8456756547": {
        "score": 2000,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

I want to do a simple ranking sorting by "score" but I have many users and I should add an indexOn in the rules to optimize:

```
"rules": {
    "users": {
        "$user": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.firebase.identities['facebook.com'][0] === $user",
            ".indexOn": ["score"]
        }
    }
}
```

Is the optimization 100% functional just when adding the indexOn in rules?
What about the users created before adding the indexOn?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

When you update your rules file (either through the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/) or through the CLI), the Firebase Database (re)creates all the indexes defined in the rules. It does this for all existing data and then continues to update those indexes for any data changes.

But you've defined the index on the wrong level. You want to allow querying of the `users` node on the individual user's scores. So you have to define the index on `users`:

```
"rules": {
    "users": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".indexOn": ["score"]
        "$user": {
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.firebase.identities['facebook.com'][0] === $user",
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice that I also moved your `.read` rule up to `users`. Because without that, you would not have read permission on `/users` and thus can't query it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! The "recreation" process will take a few seconds. Will there be problems if database receives user modification requests at that time?

Comment: If you're having problems, please provide the steps that reproduce those problems.

Comment: I asked to prevent issues from current users. No problems by the moment. Thanks!

Comment: What if you have [score] nested more than once, in different places inside users? How does FB know on which one place the index?

Comment: Each child node of `users` can only have a single child property `score`. That's the value Firebase indexes with the above rules.